# Update from angular 13 to 14 and it shows me the following error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have no idea what's going on, since everything was functional, when I updated to angular **14** I started to get that validation error.

> The error Argument of type '(((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => ValidationErrors) | ((pattern: string | RegExp) => ValidatorFn))[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)

After the `.loginEmail(email, passsword)`

```
async onLogin() {
    const { email, password } = this.loginForm.value;
    try {
      await this.authSvc
        .loginEmail(email, password)
        .then((isValid) => {
          if (isValid) {
            // console.log('correo valido, redirigir a inicio');
            this.router.navigate(['/inicio']);
            this.signAlert();
          } else {
            // TODO enviar a vista de solicitud de verificacion de correo
            // this.router.navigate(['/sendEmail'])
            // console.log('correo no valido, redirigir a sendEmail');
          }
        })
        .catch((reason) => {
          console.error(reason);
          this.emailValid = true;
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: can you add your authSvc file code pls? seems like the type doesnt match the expected type of the loginEmail function

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like when you do this.  The password field is coming through as a form control not a string.

```
const { email, password } = this.loginForm.value;
```

We can't see you form in the question.  Maybe try this instead;

```
const formValue = this.loginForm.value;

// then when you call
.loginEmail(formValue.email, formValue.password)
```